# Change fixed navigation text color when over certain divs

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, textcolor

Apologies if this is a repeat question. I've scanned the internet but haven't found a viable solution to this. My website has varying background colours, blue and white. My nav's copy is primarily set to white but I'd like it to change to black when over a div with a white background.

Initially, I found this bit of JS on here:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(window).scroll(function(){
     var lightPos = $('#light').offset().top;
     var lightHeight = $('#light').height();
     var menuPos = $('.desktop-menu').offset().top;
     var menuHeight = $('.desktop-menu').height();
     var menuPos = $('.logo').offset().top;
     var menuHeight = $('.logo').height();
     var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

     if(menuPos > lightPos && menuPos < (lightPos + lightHeight)) {
         $('.desktop-menu').addClass('menu-secondary');
         $('.desktop-menu').removeClass('menu-primary');
     }

     else {
         $('.desktop-menu').removeClass('menu-secondary');
         $('.desktop-menu').addClass('menu-primary');
     }  
     })
})
```

But this seems to not work beyond 3 containers. If I continue scrolling to other divs, no matter what id I attach to a div (#light or #dark), the text stops changing after the first 3 div containers on a page.

Thanks to anyone who can help!

EDIT:
Struggled to get codepen to work so here's an example below.

Example HTML:

```
<div class="container">
   <header>
      <nav>
         <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="#" class="menu-btn light-color">Page 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="menu-btn light-color">Page 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="menu-btn light-color">Page 3</a></li>
         </ul>
      </nav>
   </header>

   <div class="hero-container dark-background">
   </div>

   <div class="content-container light-background" id="light">
   </div>
   
   <div class="content-container dark-background">
   </div>

   <div class="content-container light-background" id="light">
   </div>

   <div class="content-container dark-background">
   </div>
   
   <div class="content-container light-background" id="light">
   </div>

   <div class="content-container dark-background">
   </div>
</div>
```

Example CSS:

```
body {
   margin: 0;
   font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
ul {
   list-style-type: none;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
header {
   display: flex;
}
.container {
   text-align: center;
}

/*-------------------- COLORS */
.dark-background {
   background: #313747;
}
.light-background {
   background: #f4f4f4;
}
.dark-color {
   color: #303030;
}
.light-color {
   color: #f4f4f4;
}

/*-------------------- NAVIGATION */
nav {
   position: fixed;
   height: auto;
   width: 100%;
   margin: auto;
   z-index: 10;
}
.menu {
   display: flex;
   padding: 2em 0 2em 3em;
   text-align: left;
   float: left;
}
.menu li a {
   margin-right: 2em;
   font-size: 1.2em;
   font-weight: 700;
   text-decoration: none;
}

/*-------------------- HERO CONTAINER */
.hero-container {
   position: relative;
   height: 100vh;
   width: 100%;
}

/*-------------------- CONTENT CONTAINER */
.content-container {
   position: relative;
   display: flex;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100vh;
   margin: auto;
}
```

Example JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(window).scroll(function(){
   var lightPos = $('#light').offset().top;
   var lightHeight = $('#light').height();
   var menuPos = $('.menu-btn').offset().top;
   var menuHeight = $('.menu-btn').height();
   var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

   if(menuPos > lightPos && menuPos < (lightPos + lightHeight)) {
      $('.menu-btn').addClass('dark-color');
      $('.menu-btn').removeClass('light-color');
   }

   else {
      $('.menu-btn').removeClass('dark-color');
      $('.menu-btn').addClass('light-color');
   }
   })
})
```

Comment: Could you add a codepen that reproduces your case?

Comment: Codepen was being really slow for me so I've updated my question with the example code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I had to change a bit your code because you were checking on ids (you shouldn't have multiple elements with the same ID),

This should be ok for your case,
so basically i create an array of light-sections and then check if scroll position is inside one of them

```js
var $ = jQuery;
$(document).ready(function () {
  var lightPos = [];
  $(".light-background").each(function () {
    lightPos.push({
      start: $(this).offset().top,
      end: $(this).offset().top + $(this).height()
    });
  });
  $(window).scroll(function () {
    var menuPos = $(".menu-btn").offset().top;
    var isInLight = !!lightPos.some((light) => {
      return light.start < menuPos && light.end > menuPos;
    });

    if (isInLight) {
      $(".menu-btn").addClass("dark-color");
      $(".menu-btn").removeClass("light-color");
    } else {
      $(".menu-btn").removeClass("dark-color");
      $(".menu-btn").addClass("light-color");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
header {
  display: flex;
}
.container {
  text-align: center;
}

/*-------------------- COLORS */
.dark-background {
  background: #313747;
}
.light-background {
  background: #f4f4f4;
}
.dark-color {
  color: #303030;
}
.light-color {
  color: #f4f4f4;
}

/*-------------------- NAVIGATION */
nav {
  position: fixed;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: 10;
}
.menu {
  display: flex;
  padding: 2em 0 2em 3em;
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
}
.menu li a {
  margin-right: 2em;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/*-------------------- HERO CONTAINER */
.hero-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

/*-------------------- CONTENT CONTAINER */
.content-container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
      <header>
        <nav>
          <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="#" class="menu-btn light-color">Page 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="menu-btn light-color">Page 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="menu-btn light-color">Page 3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </header>

      <div class="hero-container dark-background"></div>

      <div class="content-container light-background"></div>

      <div class="content-container dark-background"></div>

      <div class="content-container light-background"></div>

      <div class="content-container dark-background"></div>

      <div class="content-container light-background"></div>

      <div class="content-container dark-background"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: That's amazing, thank you, Giovanni! I'm still getting my head around JS so this is a huge help! :)

Comment: What adjustments would need to be made to introduce a third option?

Comment: You could add a new class for the new section, for example pink-background, 
then loop through all the '.pink-background' elements and create a new array (pinkPos) like I did for the light sections,
check if you are in a pink section using a 'isInPink' function and then play with the menu classes accordingly